# qmake run external script and link

Tags: qt, qt4

How to make qmake to run external script(which produces object files) and then executing linking commands without trying to run the compiler to create object files.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, and I don't know a way of doing that directly, but if you run your script to generate the object files before you run the qmake-generated Makefile, it should not rebuild the up-to-date targets. Wouldn't that work (as a workaround at least)?

Comment: I think i need to rephrase my question, actually what i wanted is to generate object file using a set of commands which has to be executed on the source files, instead of using default compiler like g++ which executes a single command. once this is done the linking has to happen normally. So actually the commands to create object file should go in to the make file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS on stackoverflow or with your preferred web search engine. Or use $$system(your_script) and include the object files in the LIBS variable.